# Can't we download old versions of a file using Box api?

Tags: box-api

I first use box api GetVersions(File) to get all the versions of a file. Now if there are any previous version I would like to download those versions. I thought by just giving the File ID which is returned in Version colloection I can retrieve the older files. But I get an exception "404 not found". Isn't there a way to download older versions of a file??

Comment: Can you specify what SDK you're using?

Comment: box-csharp-sdk-v2. https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2

Answer (score 1):

The IDs returned in the version collection are version IDs, not file IDs. You can tell because the `type` of the JSON object is `file_version`.

The result of the call to get file versions using the V2 API looks something like this:

```
GET https://api.box.com/files/12345/versions

{
    "total_count": 1,
    "entries": [
        {
            "type": "file_version",
            "id": "286582",
            "sha1": "286c42a2b9dabb536c87b1a88a6842117bfb37ab",
            "name": "This is a file.txt",
            "size": 6,
            "created_at": "2012-10-12T16:06:49-07:00",
            "modified_at": "2013-02-13T05:28:02-08:00",
            "modified_by": {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "XXXXXX",
                "name": "XXXXX",
                "login": "XXXXX@example.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The versions endpoint only lists previous versions of a file. To download the current version you can do:

`GET https://api.box.com/files/12345/content`

To download a previous version of a file, pass the `version` query string parameter with the version ID as its value. In the above example, to download this version do:

`GET https://api.box.com/files/12345/content?version=286582`

Comment: Thanks ryan. I should have noticed that the object type is file_version. I was going through https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2 . I could not see any api exposed as of now which can download a previous version of a file. https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2/blob/master/BoxApi.V2/BoxManager.File.cs  .